# How can I add assumptions on the coefficients when using FindFit?

Tags: fitting, assumptions, coefficients

I have an equation of the following type:

$$f(z) \overset{!}{=} a f_a(z) + \sum_{s=0}^\infty c(s) f_c(z,s)\tag{1}$$

where I know $f$ numerically and $f_a$ and $f_c$ analytically (they are long, complicated sums of hypergeometric functions). I also know that (i) the $c(s)$ decrease as $s$ increases, and that (ii) $f_c(z,s)$ decreases as $s$ increases. Because of that I would like to impose a cutoff on the sum in $(1)$, fit the resulting equation to the data and solve for the coefficients I chose to keep. In other words, I have:

$$f(z) \overset{!}{\sim} a f_a(z) + \sum_{s=0}^{s_\text{max}} c(s) f_c(z,s)\tag{2}$$

There is one system for which I have the coefficients analytically, which I can compare to the results of the fit. The method I exposed above works very well for $a$, which matches the analytical result very precisely.

However it clearly cannot work for the $c(s)$ (and it doesn't), because you can always choose the last coefficient in the sum to compensate for the other terms. I think it may work better if I was able to impose the following condition on the coefficients:

$$c(s) \leq c(s+1) \qquad \forall s \geq 0\tag{3}$$

Any idea how I could that? Here is how I do the fit so far:

```
nbcoefficients = 30;
fit = a*fa + Sum[c[s]*fc, {s, 0, nbcoefficients - 1}];
coefficients = Join[{a}, Table[c[s], {s, 0, nbcoefficients - 1}]];
FindFit[dataplotLO, fit, coefficients, z]
```

P.S. : I am sorry that this is not a working example per se, but for that I would have to (i) give the data somehow, which is very long and (ii) give the functions $f_a$ and $f_c$, which are very long as mentioned above.

Comment: I think I found how to add constraints, it is just of the form `FindFit[data,{fit,constraints},coefficients,variable]`. I will run some tests, and I will write an answer if it solves my question.

Comment: So it kind of works, but the result is still very inaccurate: with $300$ data points at an accuracy of $\sim 0.002$%, and with $100$ coefficients, I get errors of $\sim 10$% for the coefficient $a$, $\sim 20$% for the coefficient $c(0)$, $\sim 7$% for the coefficient $c(1)$, and $\sim 6$% for the coefficient $c(2)$, ... For some reason, it seems that the result becomes more accurate for higher $s$ (example: the error is $\sim 0.3$% for $c(9)$), which was unexpected. I am open to any suggestion for improving these results.

Comment: I suggest that you share your complete code. More detailed suggestions will depend critically on playing around with it and trying to fix it,

Comment: @MarcoB Yes I understand what you are saying. incidentally, the suggestion I made above and some reworking of the problem unrelated to the question did make the job at a quite accurate level. I will post an answer about the constraints.

Comment: Glad you were able to work something out, and thank you for summarizing it in the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easy way to implement the constraint given in $(3)$ for an arbitrary number of coefficients:

```
constraints = Table[c[s] >= c[s + 1], {s, 0, nbcoefficients - 2}];
```

Then `FindFit` should be rewritten e.g. in the following way:

```
FindFit[dataplotLO, Join[{fit}, constraints], coefficients, z];
```